# Cloud Firestore Function returns only one document?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I create a firebase function to return posts collection, for some reason cloud function return only one post(document). But when I run this function locally, in terminal I get all posts. Any idea why?

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const cors = require('cors')({origin: true});
admin.initializeApp();

exports.postWidget = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
cors(request, response, () => {});

var db = admin.firestore(); 

var postsRef = db.collection('posts')
postsRef.where('postStatus', '==', 'published').get()
.then(snapshot => {
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        let data = doc.data()
        return response.send(data)
    });
})
.catch(err => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `response.send(data)` multiple times in forEach loop.  That's not likely to do what you want, as you're only supposed to call `send()` once with then entire response.  Instead, you should be collecting all the data to send in a single object, and call `send()` with that one object.

Comment: Thanks Doug, I am sure that is the reason. If I don't see this, then it is time to finish for today :)